# How, and at what frequency should I send user events from my Android app to my server?

Tags: android

I record a lot of user actions in my app such as clicks, loading time of web pages, time on page with a lot of custom fields to be processed on server side. 
My question is what is a good frequency for sending these events to the server and where is the best way to do that- inside the app itself? using an external service? a network change receiver? etc

Comment: It probably depends on your requirements for real-time data.

Comment: Are your users aware of this?

Comment: @KristyWelsh  doesn't have to be real time at all.

Comment: I have a catalog in my app and want to know which items are favorited (clicked most) by users. users are anonymous, and never sign in. why is this malware? @DerGolem

Comment: So, you just register selected item counts. No, this is not malware.